# Burning files and directories with long unicode names

Tags: burning, unicode

Is there any CD/DVD burning app/ISO format which supports files and directories with long non-English (unicode) names? Apparently Joliet-long ISO standard supports filename up to 103 characters, but I'm not sure if it supports unicode as well, and if Brasero or any other Gnome app can burn DVDs with this format. I found out that an app called [gBurner](http://www.gburner.com/) does quite a decent job, but unluckily it's a Win app.

I have to burn the contents of my external HDD, but since my data contains many downloaded pages (with companion HTML pages' directories containing pictures, JS scripts, CSS styles, and so on) and since many of those filenames contain non-English characters, I need some app/format to be capable of burining them safely on a DVD (without the old-fashioned need to compress the contents under a English filename), such that the content is readable on Linux and Win machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### GUI Application

`k3b` is able to create `ISO Level 3` filesystem CD's with `Joliet-long`. To install type in Terminal:

```
apt-get install k3b
```

Unfortunately `k3b` is an `KDE` application so this will install lots of (unwanted) dependencies on your machine. So you might rather use the command line alternative.

#### Command Line

`mkisofs` can create .iso files with `Joliet-long` which can be burned with every other application (e.g. Brasero)

```
mkisofs -iso-level 3 -J -joliet-long -rock -input-charset utf-8 -o project.iso /path/to/files
```

In Brasero press `Burn image` select the project.iso and hit burn.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. Yes, as you said, k3b is a KDE package, it don't want to install all of those kde packages, I need a Gnome app/command. mkisofs is fine, but how can I ADD some files (again with long unicode names) to an already burnt CD/DVD/ISO file? Thank you again.

Comment: In Properties there is an option `Leave the disc open to add other files later`. So normally you should be able to create an image, burn that to CD with above option enabled. Than create a second image with only additional files and burn that, too. But at least with CD-RW's it looks like there is a bug because Brasero always ask to change CD or delete existing Data before burning. Didn't test with CD-R.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I had installed k3b on another Ubuntu installation on my machine, but I never burnt any thing with that, and then I removed the whole KDE packages, because I felt those packages had made my system pretty heavy and were a burden affecting startup time. Anyway, after reading couple of posts about the cons of Brasero and the wealth of features that k3b has, I thought it's worth to install 130 MB. I know that k3b has very strong dependencies on Qt, but since it's the most popular burning app for linux, the developers should develop a GTK version. Thank you again.

Comment: Qt or GTK are not merely tools for decorative purpose. They provide the whole framework, the whole set of tools how to write an application. It may even be that to write k3b in GTK, it would take triple the effort it took to write k3b in Qt.

Answer (score 1):

The mkisofs command given here indeed produces a filesystem
that will be able to show quite long and exotic names on
Linux and MS-Windows.

You need a Joliet tree for seeing the correct names on
MS-Windows. Linux will use the Rock Ridge extension.

Joliet is encoded in UTF-16 which is a form of Unicode.
Prescribed maximum name length is 64 chracters (= 128 byte).
The space in the directory entry would take up to 103
characters.

Rock Ridge has no specific character set. A file name can have
255 bytes of length. It will copy the name bytes as stored in
the filesystem tree. UTF-8 is fully ok.

ISO level influences maximum name length in the ISO 9660 directory
tree. Level 1 demands DOS style names (plus addon characters),
level 2 and 3 restrict name length to 30 freely choosable characters,
plus mandatory dot and semicolon, plus version number 1 to 32767.
But that is of few interest. Linux and MS-Windows will use the
info from Rock Ridge resp. Joliet.

Level 3 allows data files of 4 GiB or larger.
Beware: At least older mkisofs versions spoil their copy of
large data files. Make a test with your installed mkisofs,
if you have files of 4 GiB or larger.

I would propose to use my own program xorriso rather than mkisofs

```
xorriso -for_backup \
        -outdev /dev/sr0 \
        -blank as_needed \
        -joliet on \
        -map /path/to/files /
```

This will blank the CD, DVD, or BD in drive /dev/sr0 if the medium
is not yet blank resp. occupied by an ISO filesystem that shall be
overwritten.
It will copy the tree under /path/to/files on hard disk to a tree
under the / directory of the ISO fileystem.
Then it will create the ISO filesystem with Joliet and Rock Ridge
and burn it to the blank medium.

There will be MD5 checksums added for superblock, directory tree,
whole image, and each single data file. You may verify the burn
success of the overall image by

```
xorriso -for_backup -indev /dev/sr0 -check_media --
```

or check each single data file by

```
xorriso -for_backup -indev /dev/sr0 -check_md5_r sorry / --
```

Comment: Thank you. But two questions crossed my mind:

Comment: 1. What if I want to APPEND/ADD some files/directories to an already burnt DVD (obviously with enough free space) or an ISO file? 2. What if some of my files/directories have names more than 103 characters? I mean the total path length is 103+? Do the filenames get truncated, or directory names, or both? (how do user get notified and how can he/she specify a shorter name?) 3. I didn't completely realized: is the limit 103 Unicode characters or 103 English characters? You said "Joliet is encoded in UTF-16 which is a form of Unicode. Prescribed maximum name length is 64 chracters". Thank you.

Comment: I gave it a shot. There is a problem. It simply ignores the files with filenames longer than 240 (or 103?) characters, which I think is destructive, specially when you're making backups. It should truncate filenames instead of overlook files, and preferably displays the original name and path to users and asks him/her to enter the desired shorter name. The feature to add some files to a compilation is very important as well.

Comment: Something weird has happened: although your app (xorriso) warned about some files with long names (which I don't recall the exact files), but I marked a file with a long name before burning to test if it works with this 173-character-long filename (containing some non-English characters). And it has worked! Great! But Why did it give some warnings/errors? Have those files been different files with really long filenames (which haven't got burnt)?